# Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-boot, multipartform-data, multipart

In my current spring-boot project, I have this form to upload a war file to the server:

```
    <form:war>
        <div class="field-box">
             <label th:text="${war}"></label>
             <div class="col-md-7">
                 <input class="form-control arquivo" th:attr="data-classe=${command['class'].simpleName},target=${war}" th:id="${war}" type="file" />
             </div>
         </div>
    </form:war>
```

the form is handled by this controller method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="download", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> download(@RequestParam(value="id") String id) throws Exception {
        return this.serv.download(id);
    }
```

and by this method in the service class:

```
  public String upload(String id, String classe, String target, MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    Arquivo novo;
    if(id == null) {
      novo = new Arquivo(classe, target);
      this.dao.insert(novo);
            id = novo.getId();
    } else {
      novo = this.dao.findById(id);
    }

    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    File arquivo = new File(novo.toString());
    if(!arquivo.exists())
            if(arquivo.mkdirs())
                arquivo.createNewFile();

    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(arquivo) );
    stream.write(bytes);
    stream.close();

    return novo.getId();
  }
```

all this is triggered by this jquery code:

```
        $("input.arquivo").on("change", function(event){
            console.log('mudanca no campo de arquivo');
            var c = $(this).data('classe');
            var t = $(this).data('target');
            var f = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/Picture/upload",
                data: { classe: c, target: t, file: f },
                contentType: "multipart/form-data"
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log('id: '+data);
                $(this).attr('type', 'hidden');
                $(this).attr('name', t);
                $(this).attr('value', data)
            });
        });
```

my application.properties have this configuration:

```
# Multipart Configuration
multipart.location = ${user.home}/.lojacms/Uploads
multipart.maxFileSize = 100Mb
multipart.maxRequestSize = 100Mb
multipart.fileSizeThreshold = 10Mb
```

but when I try upload a file, I get the error described above (in the title). Anyone can tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: Could you add your controller RequestMapping for your upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then I found the solution changing the javascript code to this:

```
          $("input.arquivo").on("change", function(event){
                var c = $(this).data('classe');
                var t = $(this).data('target');

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('classe', c);
                formData.append('target', t);
                formData.append('file', $('#input_'+t)[0].files[0]);

                $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "/Arquivo/upload",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
                }).done(function(data){
                  $('#'+t).append('<input type="hidden" name="'+t+'" value="'+data+'"/>')
                });
          });
```

In short words, I am using the `FormData` element of the javascript to handle the values submited to the server, including the multipart data.